# Ignore/only show errors/warnings from certain directory using CMake

Tags: compiler-errors, cmake, qt-creator, compiler-warnings

**main question:** Is there a configuration for cmake, to show or ignore compiler warnings/errors only from a certain directory?

**alternative solution:** How can I toggle this in QtCreator?

**background / motivation**:
I'm working on a bigger CMake-project and want to focus on warnings and errors only from my subproject. I'm working with QtCreator and it annoys me to look for "my" errors/warnings under a pile of foreign ones.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can set compiler warning options in CMake at least for certain *target* or certain *files*.

```
# For target
set_target_properties(your_project_name PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "...")

# For files
set_source_files_properties(
  ${list_of_your_files}
  PROPERTIES
  COMPILE_FLAGS "..."
)
```

It is also possible to set the options per-folder basis by separating your project as subproject, add it using `add_subdirectory(your_project)` and in your project CMakeLists.txt use `add_definitions(...)`.

From CMake documentation:

> [add_definitions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:add_definitions)  Adds flags to the compiler command line for sources in the current directory and below.

Comment: Interesting. The `set_source_files_properties()` is per directory. So all named targets are affected, whatever the project it's in...

Comment: _Note: This property [a.k.a. COMPILE_FLAGS] has been superseded by the COMPILE_OPTIONS property._ In case you are using newer versions of cmake.

Answer (score 11):

Basically the same as @ronkot's answer. But don't need `add_subdirectory` for certain directory, using `set_source_files_properties` with `file(GLOB_RECURSE ...)` also works.

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_DIR "SRC_DIR/*.c" "SRC_DIR/*.h")

set_source_files_properties(
  ${SRC_DIR}
  PROPERTIES
  COMPILE_FLAGS "-w"
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on @ronkot answer, the recommended target-based approach would be:

```
target_compile_options(your_target SCOPE compiler-warning-options)
```

Where `SCOPE` is `PUBLIC|INTERFACE|PRIVATE`, and `compiler-warning-options` are actual compiler warning options, such as `-Wall`.  See [cmake's docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.19/command/target_compile_options.html?highlight=target_compile_options) for more info.

In general, prefer a target-based approach with modern CMake (3.0+) rather than a directory-based approach.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work correctly to actually add the option to specific files, rather than dropping all the pre-set options as the other answers do:

```
set_source_files_properties(
    "../src/io/filesystem/zip/ioapi.c"
    "../src/io/filesystem/zip/unzip.c"
    "../src/io/filesystem/zip/zip.c"
    PROPERTIES APPEND_STRING PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS " -w"
)
```