# How to set compiler flags for groups of files in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

In my CMake project I set up compiler flags like this:

```
if (MSVC)
    # Build cpp files on all cores
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /MP /W4")

    # can't use the "secure" versions as they're Windows specific
    add_definitions("/D\"_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS\"")
    add_definitions("/D\"_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS\"")

    add_definitions("/wd4290")
else()
    # Enable C++11, you may need to use -std=c++0x if using an older gcc compiler
    if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
        SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
    else()
        SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wno-unused-parameter -fPIC -Wall -Weffc++ -pedantic")
    endif()
endif()
```

To set the flags for MSVC, Clang and GCC. However in my source files var I have my source code and 3rd party things like gtest and gmock.

How can I set these flags such that they only apply to some subset of my source code?

E.g

```
# This should use the flags set above
SET(source
mycode/mysrc.cpp)

# This should not use the flags from above
SET(not_my_source
3rdparty/3rdparty.cpp)

# But both end up being part of the same executable
add_executable(Test ${source} ${not_my_source})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CMake - ignore/only show errors/warnings from certain directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133332/cmake-ignore-only-show-errors-warnings-from-certain-directory)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638408/cmake-override-compile-flags-for-single-files). You should be able to pass a list of files that you want to change the compiler flags for.